Try to install xformer, but it automatically upgrade my torch and its liability. How to fix it?
As the xformer upgraded, it also provid more support to the newest version of pytorch. So when try to install xformer from pip:
pip install xformer

It always try to upgrade the pytorch, which I don't want to.
I tried to check the original repository of xformer
I found every tag has its associate pytorch version.
For example,
I have pytorch 2.4.1, I searched the tags of it.
the version that newer than 0.0.28.post2 will support torch >= 2.5.0
0.0.28.post1 support pytorch 2.4.1
so just try
pip install xformers==0.0.28.post1

or install form source.
pip install ninja


pip install -v -U git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/xformers.git@v0.0.28.post1#egg=xformers


I tried pip install xformers==0.0.28.post1 --no-dependencies, but then I get an error "xFormers was built for: PyTorch 2.4.1+cu121" so that doesn't seem like it works.

I could not replicate your problem. I use the docker image pytorch/pytorch:2.4.1-cuda12.4-cudnn9-runtime. Then I entered two commands: apt update && apt install build-essential ninja-build git to get the build dependencies and your pip install git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/xformers.git@v0.0.28.post1#egg=xformers. And it works. I assume your -U option might force pip to override the tagged option specified? Note that even if I add the -U, I do not have the post2 version installed by pip.
